# Transforming unrestricted variable in Linear Programming

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

In two books of Dantzig, there is a theorem which attribute to Tucker, but no citation is provide.
Generally, every one unrestricted variable can be transformed two non-negative variables. It says that n unrestricted variable can be transformed n+1 non-negative variables, instead 2n variables.

[image]

[image]

[image]

How this result can be proved, or where can find the proof?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea of the first transformation with $2n$ variables is to interpret $x_j'$ as the positive part $\max(x_j,0)$ and $x_j''$ as the negative part $\max(-x_j,0)$.

For the second transformation with $n+1$ variables, $x_0$ represents the most negative part $$\max_{j\in\{1,\dots,n\}} \max(-x_j,0),$$ and $x_j'$ represents $x_j+x_0$.

Comment: Many thanks! I have another related question about absolute value. If the objective is min c|x|, where c>0, then it is possible to linearlize by using |x|=x1+x2 and x=x1-x2. But is it possible linearlize the MP if  c<0, or with constraint like 2|x|+3|y|=4?  Btw, I find someone use y>x and y>-x to linearlize a MP with absolute value. Is the approach equivalent to, or more powerful than |x|=x1+x2 and x=x1-x2.

Comment: Glad to help. Please start a new post for each additional question.